# SQL Server 2005/2008 logging connections

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I audit SQL connections to the database from

- Windows credential
- Sql Users

Is there some built-in feature where I can determine number of:

- all connection
- active connection
- unclosed connection
- current status
- historical prevue

I hope that I'm going right way. I have application that takes all RAM to the SQL Engine and transaction logs raising to the unbelievable size on HDD durring one-two days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you're not going about this in the right way.

> I have application that be able to take all RAM to the SQL Engine

SQL Server will use as much as it needs unless you limit it. Read Brent Ozar's [A Sysadmin’s Guide to Microsoft SQL Server Memory](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/09/sysadmins-guide-microsoft-sql-server-memory/).

> transaction logs raising to the unbelievable size on HDD during
>   one-two days

9 times out of 10 this is due to the database being in FULL recovery and no log backups being taken. See Paul Randall's article [Running Out of Transaction Log Space](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Search-Engine-QA-1-Running-out-of-transaction-log-space.aspx).

If you want to monitor the items you listed:

- [Using SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx)
- [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com)
- [SQL Server Perfmon Best Practices](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2006/12/dba-101-using-perfmon-for-sql-performance-tuning/)

Comment: +1 `1)` engine has already limit in 2.5Gb from available 8Gb, `2)` there are longer time three databases on one instance, that have got linked own aplications and with sometime too hard transactions, etc...,but with clear life_cycle, without taking RAM and raising Transaction Log to the extreme amount, but in the last week I added there another 4th. aplication that ... I don't know what, where I must to start, I look at connections, live and runned queries, then live Objects, everything (my view) talking about unclosed connections with unclosed Objects ...

Comment: Perfmon counter SQLServer:General Statistics:User connections. If this is climbing continuously, you have open connections that are not being closed.

Comment: thanks for edit, in this moment you're gave me more informations as I able ..:-),